# How to create a variable based on the first observation of another variable in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to groupby ID and create a new variable *New_Variable* which takes the first value of the variable *Value* in pandas dataframe.

Current table:

```
   ID, Date, Value
    A    Jan     5   
    A    Feb     10   
    A    Mar     7   
    B    Feb     3   
    B    Mar     6    

Desired table:
  
   ID, Date,  Value, New_Variable
    A    Jan     5      5
    A    Feb     10     5
    A    Mar     7      5
    B    Feb     3      3
    B    Mar     6      3
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score -1):

You can `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df['New_variable'] = df.groupby('ID')['Value'].transform('first')
```

Output:

```
   ID  Date  Value  New_Variable
0   A   Jan      5             5
1   A   Feb     10             5
2   A   Mar      7             5
3   B   Feb      3             3
4   B   Mar      6             3
```